# Format Python String

Tags: python, string, slack-api

Estoy intentando formatear una cadena de texto en Python, pero estoy obteniendo este error:

> KeyError: '\n\t\t\t"type"'.

Este es el string en cuestión:

```
HEALTH_CONDITION_MSG = """
    [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": ":alert: Estado de Salud de {app} :alert:"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "text": "*November 12, 2019*  |  Notificaciones Team Ursucop",
                    "type": "mrkdwn"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": " :loud_sound: *Application* :loud_sound:"
            }
        }
    ]
"""
```

Y esta es la función desde la que invoco a dicho string

```
def get_message_template(self):
    return str(HEALTH_CONDITION_MSG).format(app=self.asset_id, 
            previous_state=self.previous_state, new_state=self.new_state)
```

Estoy intentando enviar un mensaje de Slack utilizando un mensaje template que diseñé, al que tengo que pasarle determinados parámetros dependiendo la situación.

Podrían ayudarme porfavor?
Gracias!

Comment: EDIT: el string esta recortado, pero a los fines de la pregunta no deberia cambiar. Es un string más largo, con otros parámetros que invoco de la misma forma que {app}.

Comment: Cuando usas `format`, Python reemplaza todo lo que está entre "{}" por el valor de la expresión encerrada entre dichos "{}".  Ese es la causa del error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Esto es un problema con el que te vas a encontrar siempre que las llaves formen parte de la cadena. Sucede por ejemplo con las regex y el snbt del juego Minecraft.

El problema es que las {} en el template cumplen dos propositos: formatear la cadena y el proposito que tengan en la sintaxis del template. Cuando usas format o f-strings, Python asume que el proposito es formatear la cadena, derivando en errores extraños como ese.

#### Primera solución

Si no querés dejar de usar este modo de formato, tendrás que escapar todas y cada una de las llaves que no uses para formatear la cadena. Como? Con otras llaves xD

Ejemplo:

```
nombre = "Dante S."
print(f"{{hola}} {nombre}")
```

#### Segunda solución (mi preferida)

En estos casos, me gusta más optar por el modo antiguo de formatear cadenas: [el estilo printf](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). Hay mucha información sobre él al respecto en internet.

```
nombre = "Dante S."
print("{hola} %s" % nombre)
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa cuando el reemplazo está anidado? Ejemplo: reemplazar `app` en  `"{Salud de {app} :alert:}"`

Comment: Escapas solo las llaves de afuera

Answer (score 0):

El problema ya te lo dijeron, format está tratando de reemplazar todo lo que esté entre llaves.

Otra solución alternativa y casi nada invasiva con el código que ya tienes es con [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings)

```py
from string import Template

# ....

def get_message_template(self):
    t = Template(HEALTH_CONDITION_MSG)
    return t.substitute(app=self.asset_id, 
            previous_state=self.previous_state, new_state=self.new_state)
```

Para que funcione, en el string `HEALTH_CONDITION_MSG` le colocas un signo de dolar antes de las llaves donde va el reemplazo:

```py
"text": "... de ${app} :alert:"
#               ^-- El símbolo
```